# Header attributes in xml doc

Tags: php, xml, api

How do you get the attributes in the root node of a xml doc?

```
<xbox status="success" version="0.0.9">
</xbox>
```

So I can check for a error:

```
if( ? == 'success'){
    //success
}else{
    //error
}
```

Comment: Do you mean the root node of the XML document, which isn't necessarily called "xml," or do you mean the XML doctype (`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>`)?

Comment: @sdleihssirhc the root node I edit OP..

Answer (score 1):

You cannot access the attributes of the root node directly from the DOMDocument. The workaround is to search for the tag first, then get the value:

```
$d = new DOMDocument;
$d->loadXML('<xml status="success" version="0.0.9"></xml>');

print $d->getElementsByTagName("xml")->item(0)->getAttribute("version");
```

Answer (score 0):

The only attributes you may use in  (and mind the question marks) header are "version" and "encoding".

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried simple XML ( http://php.net/manual/fr/book.simplexml.php ) ?

Example ( adapted from a note of the manual ):

```
<?php
$sxml= new SimpleXmlElement($xmlstr);

if( (string) $sxml->attributes()->status== "success"){
    //success
}else{
    //error
}

?>
```

Answer (score -1):

I just did this:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string('<xbox status="success" version="0.0.9"></xbox>');
$status = $xml{status};

if($status == 'success'){
    echo 'Success!';
} else {
    echo 'Error!';
}
```

Comment: That look pretty much like my suggestion ;) But beware, you're comparing a SimpleXMLElement with a string. You should always type cast everything that you extract from SimpleXML, or you could have some trouble.